# Why the import * as fs from 'fs' doesn't work and gives me an error?

Tags: javascript, import, requirejs, node.js-fs

So this is my problem:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

var downloads = 0;

const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('tp.txt', (err, inputD) => {
   if (err) throw err;
      downloads = inputD.toString();
})

setInterval(function (){
    fs.readFile('tp.txt', (err, inputD) => {
        if (err) throw err;
           downloads = inputD.toString();
     })
    document.getElementById("downloads").innerText = downloads;
}, 5000)
```

But I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module error

I was trying to read from a file but I couldn't!

I searched everywhere but I can't find my soulution.

Comment: because you are using serverside node in the browser. That is not how you read the contents of a file on the clientside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are writing CommonJS (CJS), you can just remove the `import * as fs from 'fs';` line (that is ESM syntax). The only line you need to import `fs` is this one: `const fs = require('fs')`, which you already have.

If you want to use `import`-style syntax (ESM), add `"type": "module",` to your `package.json` and remove the `const fs = require('fs')` line instead.

Comment: Thanks, but when I don't use it it says"require() is not defined" so I added this:

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/"></script>
    <script type="module" src="milsymbol-2.0.0/src/milsymbol.js"></script>

Then it gave me this:

   at r ((index):5:13)
    at ka ((index):11:354)
    at t ((index):5:107)
    at script.js:8:12

I am soo done of js, and also when I tried to transform it to Node js it just didn't work, it didn't say anyting in the terminal\

Comment: I just tried to run it in a Node environment it works in the log but in my browser it's still broken

Comment: Yes @Sadra I was under the assumption you were writing code for local Node.js.